# Are consecutive relationships necessary when doing multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there a difference in the results or a difference in performance between these two statements/examples:

Example 1 (Consecutive INNER Relationship)

```
    SELECT ID FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID
    INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
```

Example 2 (Non-Consecutive INNER Relationship)

```
    SELECT ID FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID
    INNER JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T.ID = T3.ID
```

---

or between these 2 statements/examples:

Example 1 (Consecutive LEFT Relationship)

```
    SELECT ID FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
```

Example 2 (Non-Consecutive LEFT Relationship)

```
    SELECT ID FROM TABLE T
    INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T.ID = T2.ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T.ID = T3.ID
```

The only difference is the second `Join` is on the `Table` whereas the first example is on `Table2`.  I'm pretty sure they return the same thing, but I'm just looking for more experienced answers here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared actual execution plans?

Comment: The results should be the same.

Comment: I do think the results would be the same, but how about on performance?

Comment: Well, that's where I would compare actual execution plans between the two queries.

Comment: I'd be shocked if there was any performance difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in results. The statements are functionally equivalent.

The difference in performance depends on the specific database and version, and on the data.

My experience is that in a simple case like this there is typically no difference in performance between the two queries. The SQL2008 optimizer will run the join in whatever order makes sense according to statistics (size of tables, availability of indexes), regardless which way you write this query.

Comment: does it apply for the examples with the `LEFT` statement in it as well?

Comment: Yes, the LEFT JOIN at the end still works the same.  If the LEFT JOIN were before the INNER JOIN, that would produce different results for ID's in the first and third tables but not the second.